# Intersection points between a line and polyline

Tags: matlab, line, polyline

It is known that the intersection points between a line and a polyline can be found using [Polyxpoly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) command in MATLAB.
However, the examples given here involve the polylines that are composed of points, but not real lines. Here, a polyline object is created with the interpolation of space between the points.
What I want to do is to obtain the intersection points between the polyline and line that are defined by **line equations**, but not from a point to another. [image: Image below is to illustrate what I'm looking for]

I want to obtain the coordinates of the intersection points in MATLAB (Denoted with blue circles).

Comment: this looks like a simple algebra problem, if you have the equations of the line and the eq of the polygon... see for example http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html

Comment: If you create a line segment by choosing two points on your infinite line which are outside the polyline, then you'll have what you need for polyxpoly.  Choose, for example, x=min(black_polyline_x) - 100, and max(black_polyline_x) + 100

Comment: @Peter this seems like a good solution. How come I could not think of it! You can add your comment as answer if you want, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a line segment by choosing two points on your infinite line which are outside the polyline, then you'll have what you need for `polyxpoly`. Choose, for example,

```
x0=min(black_polyline_x) - 100;
x1=max(black_polyline_x) + 100;
```

Then compute y0 and y1 to be on the line.